# default configuration change for SBT

Tags: sbt, ibm-sbt

I integrated SBT in my existing application and able to run the application with sbt enabled. I deployed in my test server and it works fine but when I moved to the production, Since the context path of the application is different it breaks.

Ex: in test server my application url is 
https://somedomian/SampleSbt

In production
htt....somedomain/serve/meth/SampleSbt

I'm getting error in firebug as
htt.....domain/sbt/js/sdk/sbt/ErrorTransport.js -> Forbidden

I tried changing the context path /my code path /managed-beans.xml and many ways but still it gives the same error

want to change the path from http.....somedomain/sbt/js/sdk/sbt/Errortransport.js to http.....somedomain/serv/meth/sbt/js/sdk/sbt/Errortransport.js

Comment: someone on my team will look at this shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion yesterday with Projjwal Saha, the issue should be resolved. 
Can you update if it is, or let us know in case you still see the issue.

Comment: Yes the issue is resolved just by changing the param value to toolKitUrl.
thanks Projjwal

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to add the servlet init parameter called "toolkitUrl" to the library servlet, defined in your application web.xml  with value "%local_server%/somedomain/serv/meth/sbt".

So the modified library servlet declaration should look like -

`<servlet>
        <description>This servlet initializes the specified JavaScript library for use by the Social Business Toolkit.</description>
        <display-name>Social Business Toolkit Library Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>LibraryServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.sbt.jslibrary.servlet.LibraryServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>toolkitUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>%local_server%/somedomain/serv/meth/sbt</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>`

Comment: Actually tried with

'code'
'<init-param>
   <param-name>toolkitExtUrl</param-name>
   <param-value>%local_server%/sbtx</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>jsLibraryUrl</param-name>
   <param-value>%local_server%/serv/meth/sbt/js/libs</param-value>
  </init-param>'
'code'

Comment: Please correct the param name to use "toolkitUrl" and check.